# Checking if all numbers in a List are repeated

Tags: c#

I need to validate phone number to check if they are all 1's or 2's or 3's etc. How do I effectively do that using LINK. The phone number is in a string. 
So if its "2323456789" is should return true and if its "3333333333" is should return false. I searched every where for a solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this?

```
public bool Check(String number)
{
   return number.Distinct().Count() > 1;
}
```

Comment: You don't need `.ToCharArray()`, the `String` class is already `IEnumerable<char>`.

Comment: Although when I passed something like this -> 2142371942 The Distinct.count was 6. Not sure how it deduced that, but it always returns Distinct.Count = 1 for all 0's, 1's, 2's .... 9's so thats what I need.

Comment: @MissTech for 2142371942 it returned 6 because that string contains 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, and 9 a total of 6 different characters.

Comment: @Guffa You're right, I'll update my answer to remove the ToCharArray().

Answer (score 2):

Check out this article on validating phone numbers:

http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/validate-phone-number

to quote from the document:

Area codes start with a number from 2–9, followed by 0–8, and then any third digit.
The second group of three digits, known as the central office or exchange code, starts with a number from 2–9, followed by any two digits.
The final four digits, known as the station code, have no restrictions.

So ya, maybe someone could put in 222-222-2222.

Comment: While interesting, that link doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I checked that one. We have all the validations except this one needed for a specific case. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Linq? Just to check if a string consists of the same character repeated multiple times?

The following regular expression will match a string consisting solely of the same decimal digit repeated multiple times. That is to say, it will match "11" , "111"  and "111", but not "1". If you want to to match any string consisting of the same decimal digits repeated 0 or more times, replace the 1-or-more quantifier character `+` character with the zero-or-more quantifier `*`.

```
private static Regex rxBogusPhoneNumber = new Regex( @"^(?<digit>\d)\k<digit>+$" ) ;
public static bool isBogusPhoneNumber( string phoneNumber )
{
  return rxBogusPhoneNumber.IsMatch( phoneNumber ) ;
}
```

Cheers!